# Whitelist certain urls for my network

Tags: networking, router, web, web-filtering, traffic-filtering

i have a network with several hosts (not more than 10) and I want to allow access to certain URLs that means whitelisting certain URLs and dropping the rest for certain hosts. For example I want the IP 192.168.1.1 to have unrestricted access but 192.168.1.2 to have access only to [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com).

I bought ER605 TP-Link which was supposed to have this function but it doesn't seem to work properly. I placed it between my router and my main switch and I set up for all hosts to have gateway the ER605. All hosts have unrestricted access to all websites even after web filtering rules. Is there any other easy way to do it ?

Comment: If you have followed your [manual](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/er605/) section "2.1.2 Configuring URL Filtering" page 137, please take screenshots of the relevant screens and [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1833868/edit) them into your post.